# Error trying to install composer require mailchimp

Tags: magento2.4.4, mailchimp

I am trying to install mailchimp

I have 2..4.4 magento running on php 8.1

when running this command in SSH

composer require mailchimp/mc-magento2/v103.4.50

I get the following

```
Class "Magento\Setup\Mvc\Bootstrap\InitParamListener" not found#0 /home/831195.cloudwaysapps.com/yjxddjbsxh/public_html/vendor/magento/framewo
rk/Console/Cli.php(78): require()                                                                                                             
#1 /home/831195.cloudwaysapps.com/yjxddjbsxh/public_html/bin/magento(22): Magento\Framework\Console\Cli->__construct()                        
#2 {main}
```

I have successfully installed it on my cloned staging app which s on the same server as production. I am unable to install it on the production environment using the same methods I successfully installed it on the staging site.

Does anyone have any idea on how to resolve this issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the solution below:

- Remove `setup` and `vendor/magento/magento2-base` folders: `rm -rf setup vendor/magento/magento2-base`
- Clear composer cache: `composer clear-cache`
- Run your composer command, in your case, it is `composer require mailchimp/mc-magento2/v103.4.50`

Notice: I don’t recommend doing that directly on production as it is high risk. You should implement it on your local or testing server first, then deploy the changes to production.

Assuming you are fine with the risk and still need to implement it on the production server, please **backup** `files`  and `database`, and enable Magento maintenance mode before you implement it. Once you have done it without any issues, disable Magento maintenance mode.
Command to enable Magento maintenance mode: `bin/magento maintenance:enable`
Command to disable Magento maintenance mode: `bin/magento maintenance:disable`

You can read more about "Enable and Disable maintenance mode" from the official Magento document: https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/commerce-operations/installation-guide/tutorials/maintenance-mode.html

Comment: removing vendor file worked

Comment: delete the folder vendor and run composer install again

Comment: from composer do rm -rf vendo/

Comment: then do composer install

Comment: Glad to hear that. Please please mark my answer as **accepted** (click the check symbol at the top-left corner of my answer). That indicates your issue is solved and helps others with the same issue find out the verified answer easily.